# Remove the row from dataframe if the column(position) contains a value from list

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, data-cleaning, fuzzy-logic

Here is the sample dataframe which has three column and a list [image]

My goal is to delete rows if column [position] contains the value from list. Lets say if list has a value sales then our code should find and delete row even if it is between the string of columns position

I have tired fuzzy matching but it didn't help me out.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: I found a solution that I will share shortly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it. The assumption is that the words are case insensitive. Which means that `sales` in the `elimination_list` will eliminate positions that contain the words `Sales or sales or SALES` etc

In the example below, I have chosen to eliminate the words `sales` and `marketing`.
The strings in the `position` column are converted to lowercase before checking if they contain any of the words in the elimination_list.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"firstname":['Roy','Kean','Mark','Smith', 'Jao'],
                  "lastname":['Ran','Sam','Stonis','Steve','Felx'],
                  "position":['Sales Manager','Group Chief sales Officer','marketing Manager','Data Analyst','Developer']})

# Enter words used to eliminate rows
elimination_list = ['sales','marketing']

# Select rows based on elimination list
rows_to_keep=[]
for substring in df.position:
    word_list = substring.lower().split()
    rows_to_keep.append(not bool(set(word_list) & set(elimination_list)))
        
# Create a new dataframe (output)            
output = df[rows_to_keep]   
print(output)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  firstname lastname      position
3     Smith    Steve  Data Analyst
4       Jao     Felx     Developer
```